# Converting Zulu Date/Time to Just Date Using Python and Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have start and end times that look as follows:

Start: 2017-03-05T19:18:53Z

End: 2017-03-05T19:57:54.042000Z

Current iteration that leaves me with the right format but the wrong dtype:

```
format_time_user_df[['start', 'end']] = format_time_user_df[['start', 'end']].apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce')
cols = ['start', 'end']
format_time_user_df[cols] = format_time_user_df[cols].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, unit='ms').dt.date)
```

resulting in the start and end times that look as follows:

Start: 2017-03-05

End: 2017-03-05

but these are now objects and not dates.

What I am trying to accomplish is to get the dates into ascending order and also, if there is a way to section of a week at a time (Monday through Sunday) for data analysis.

Comment: The `Z` is just the way the datetime object is rendered. You can have it removed, but you have to store the dates as strings, not as dates. Are you fine with that?

Comment: @richardec. Can you try my setup and use `df.loc[:, ['start', 'end']] = df.loc[:, ['start', 'end']].apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce')`. Now check the dtypes: `df.dtypes`. What do you have?

Comment: Both `start` and `end` are `object` when I do that, @Corralien.

Comment: @richardec. It's so weird! Only the values are updated not the column itself, so the `dt` accessor is not available.

Comment: @user3727648, Can you update your post with the output of `format_time_user_df.dtypes` after applying `to_datetime`, please?

Comment: Hmm, I see you're point, and I agree, that is weird. Probably there, there's an explanation... :)

Comment: I updated the problem as well as what I am ultimately trying to accomplish. Maybe I am going about this the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `.loc[:, ...] =`, your values will be updated but the column not, so:

Replace:

```
df.loc[:, ['start', 'end']] = ...
```

By:

```
df[['start', 'end']] = ...
```

Now you can use:

```
>>> df['start'].dt.normalize()
0   2017-03-05 00:00:00+00:00
Name: start, dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

Setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'start': ['2017-03-05T19:18:53Z'],
                   'end': ['2017-03-05T19:57:54.042000Z']})
```